# Blue Prism new Excel VBO to color cells

Tags: vb.net, blueprism

I created a Excel VBO Extension object to add new functionality to the Excel steps. In my new object I would like to color a cell based on input.

For this I use the Create instance, Open Workbook, Show actions from the original Excel VBO.
The following action is my new action, but I always get the following error: "Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: The given key was not present in the dictionary."

In my new action I use the Activate Worksheet, CheckInstanceAndWorkbook, CheckInstanceHandle actions copied from the original Excel VBO and recreated in my new Excel VBO Extension object.

How can I catch the instance with my object, that has been already created by teh original Excel VBO?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you have indicates that Actions that you are using:

**Create instance, Open Workbook, Show actions from the original Excel VBO**

Belong to a different part of code which generates your **handle** variable in order for Blue Prism to manipulate your Excel Application.

Since your new object is under your **Excel VBO Extension** along with **Activate Worksheet, CheckInstanceAndWorkbook, CheckInstanceHandle actions** that were recreated, they do not have access to the **handle** variable created by a different object (in this case original Excel VBO).

*So imagine this as having two functions were as the first one generates the variable as output but the second one does not receive it as input.*

So what you need to do is to **duplicate** all the actions that you need from **original Excel VBO** to your **Excel VBO extended** and use actions of **one object only**.

Hope these information will be useful.

Comment: You may be ancillarily interested in the official guidance on [Extending the MS Excel VBO](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-11/Extending%20MS%20Excel%20VBO.PDF).